# How to use @State and @Binding parallel?

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui

**My setup:**
I am having a `ContentView` that represents a the length of a final `selection` (`selection.count`). Therefore I need a `selection` variable on my `ContentView` using a `@State` `propertyWrapper` since I want the `View` to get update as soon as the value changes. The selection is supposed to be made on my `SelectionView` therefore I am creating a `Binding` between my `selection` variables on the `ContentView` and `SelectionView`.

**My Problem:** The UI on my `SelectionView` is supposed to be updated as well when the `selection` variable changes but since it is using `@Binding` and not `@State` the view does not get updated. So I would need something where I can use a `@State` and `@Binding` at the same time or a `@Binding` which also makes the UI reload.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: [Int] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(destination: SelectionView(selection: $selection)) {
                    Text("Selection: \(selection.count)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SelectionView: View {
    @Binding var selection: [Int]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach((0...9).identified(by: \.self)) { i in
                    Button(action: {
                        if self.selection.contains(i) {
                            self.selection = self.selection.filter { !($0 == i) }
                        } else {
                            self.selection.append(i)
                        }
                    }) {
                        if self.selection.contains(i) {
                            Text("Unselect \(i)")
                        } else {
                            Text("Select \(i)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** If I am using `@State` on the `SelectionView` instead of `@Binding` it works properly (which obviously requires me to not create the binding which I want).

Comment: Please show _real_ code, not some meaningless excerpts.

Comment: I fixed the code. But this example represents my problem perfectly: Selection on one view & changes to `selection` should be visible right away (`@State`) and the `selection` variables should be bound to save changes on `ContentView` (`@Binding`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @robmayoff I was able to solve the problem. It was a problem with Xcode 11 Beta 3, installing the newest beta version solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your binding. It is the right thing to do and it works the way you want it to. A binding is the way you pass mutable state around in SwiftUI, and you are doing that, and it works. A change to a binding *does* make the view reload.

To convince yourself of that, just get rid of all the extra stuff in your example, and concentrate on the heart of the matter, the binding:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: [Int] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(destination: SelectionView(selection: $selection)) {
                    Text("Selection: \(selection.count)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct SelectionView: View {
    @Binding var selection: [Int]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button.init("Append") {
                    self.selection.append(1)
                }
                Text("Selection: \(selection.count)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run the example, tap the link, tap the button repeatedly. The display of `selection.count` is changed in both views. That's what you wanted and that's what happens.

Here's a variant on your original code that displays `selection` more explicitly (instead of `selection.count`), and you can see that the right thing is happening:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: [Int] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(destination: SelectionView(selection: $selection)) {
                    Text("Selection: \(String(describing:selection))")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct SelectionView: View {
    @Binding var selection: [Int]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0...9, id:\.self) { i in
                    Button(action: {
                        if let ix = self.selection.firstIndex(of:i) {
                            self.selection.remove(at: ix)
                        } else {
                            self.selection.append(i)
                        }
                    }) {
                        if self.selection.contains(i) {
                            Text("Unselect \(i)")
                        } else {
                            Text("Select \(i)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Neither the first nor the second one works for me. Both have the same problem: I navigate to the `SelectionView` start selecting and the UI does not get re-rendered (that means neither `Text("Selection: \(selection.count)")` nor `Text("(Un)select \(i)")` get updated), then I navigate back in both cases the UI gets updated (meaning: `Text("Selection: \(selection.count)")` and `Text("Selection: \(String(describing:selection))")` get properly rendered), and when navigating to `SelectionView` again the UI is rendered properly too. The issue is just that the buttons don't make the view re-render.

Comment: I am not understanding what "Neither the first nor the second one works for me" means. I have shown you effectively the entire content of my test app, and I've told you how it behaves. I tap a button on the second v.c. and the button texts _are_ updated, and when we go back to the first v.c., it _has_ been updated. That's just a fact. If you're doing something else that causes that not to be the case, you have not revealed its existence. Short of emailing you the actual project I don't see what else I can do.

Comment: It appears to me that this is a bug because I created a new SwiftUI project **copied** the first part of your code and it just does not work. Tried the same for the the second code part of your answer and same issue (the one I described in my above comment)

Comment: Added screencast. It's doing just what I would expect (which is what I thought you were after).

Comment: What version of Xcode are you each running, @matt and @LStephan?

Comment: @robmayoff beta 5 here, I always use the latest one, esp. since SwiftUI is such a moving target; the OP's code wouldn't compile because `identified(by:)` is gone so I had to change that part.

Comment: that might be the problem I am using Version 11.0 beta 3. I am gonna give you an update if beta 5 changes anything for me

Comment: This works for me in Xcode 12.2, but the preview doesn't work. `self.selection` isn't changed. I use `@State static var selection = ["1"]` in the Previews struct to allow bindings. Any idea how to tell preview to work in live mode?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is: upgrade to the latest Xcode.

---

I tested your code in a playground under Xcode 11 beta 4 and it worked correctly.

I tested your code in a playground under Xcode 11 beta 3 and it failed in the way you describe (I think).

The current version of Xcode 11 as of this answer is beta 5, under which your code doesn't compile because the `identified(by:)` modifier has been removed. When I changed your code to work under beta 5, by replacing `ForEach((0...9).identified(by: \.self))` with `ForEach(0...9, id: \.self)`, it worked correctly.

Therefore I deduce that you are still running beta 2 or beta 3. (`Form` wasn't available in beta 1 so I know you're not using that version.)

---

Please understand that, at the moment, SwiftUI is still quite buggy, and also still undergoing incompatible API changes. The bugs are unfortunate, but the API evolution is **good**. It's better that we suffer a few months of changes now than years of less optimal API later.

This means that you need to try to stay on the latest Xcode 11 beta unless it introduces bugs (like the `Path` bug in beta 5, if your app uses `Path`) that prevent you from making any progress.